# "key" argument keyword-only in list.sort() , but positional-or-keyword in sorted()

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, sorting

In Python 3, `lists` can be sorted in two ways. Either in place, using [`list.sort(*, key=None, reverse=None)`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=sort#list.sort) or by generating a new list using [`sorted(iterable, key=None, reverse=None)`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html?highlight=sorted#sorted).

As can be seen from the signatures, `key` is a [keyword-only](https://docs.python.org/3.6/glossary.html#keyword-only-parameter) argument in `list.sort()`, but a position-or-keyword argument in `sorted()`. This means that a call like this will fail:

```
>>> [{'i': 42}, {'i': 0}].sort(lambda x:x['i'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: must use keyword argument for key function
```

It has to be written like this:

```
>>> [{'i': 42}, {'i': 0}].sort(key=lambda x:x['i'])
```

What is the reasoning behind this? I assume one would use keyword-only arguments to enforce clearer code, is that correct? If so, why have it two different ways in these - arguably very similar - functions?

Comment: have you tried providing `key` as a positional argument for `sorted`? It will fail, you need to use a keyword argument. The docs *you link* state: *Has two optional arguments which must be specified as keyword arguments.*

Comment: I actually didn't. Silly me, sorry.

Comment: Meh, it happens :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sorted` in fact also requires `key` and `reverse` as keyword arguments; the documentation explicitly says so:

> Has two optional arguments which must be specified as keyword arguments.

Only the function signature (incorrectly) does not contain the `*`; likely an oversight in the documentation.

Comment: My fault, should've actually tried it, not asked a question after just reading the function signature.

Comment: I've prepared a PR that fixes this discrepancy, and it's merged to 3.6 and master branches, see [PR#2706](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/2706) and [PR#2709](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/2709)